# Can neon registers be indexed?

Tags: neon

Consider a neon register such as:

```
uint16x8_t foo;
```

To access an individual lane, one is supposed to use `vgetq_lane_u16(foo, 3)`. However, one might be tempted to write `foo[3]` instead given the intuition that `foo` is an array of shorts. When doing so, the gcc (10) compiles without warnings, but it is not clear that it does what it was intended to do.

The [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) does not specifically mention the indexed access, but it says that operations behave like C++ `valarray`s. Those do support indexed access in the intuitive way.

Regardless of what `foo[3]` evaluates to, doing so seems to be faster than `vgetq_lane_u16(foo, 3)`, so probably they're different or we wouldn't need both.

So what exactly does `foo[3]` mean? Is its behavior defined at all? If not, why does gcc happily compile it?

Comment: As long as the inex number is an immediate value and not a variable, the compiler gets the job done, provided you are building for `aarch64`

Comment: The question targets 32bit arm and the value also happens to be a variable (though `vgetq_lane_u16` does not accept non-constant indices).

Comment: Then no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The `foo[3]` form is the GCC Vector extension form, as you have [found and linked documentation to](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html); it behaves as so:

> Vectors can be subscripted as if the vector were an array with the same number of elements and base type. Out of bound accesses invoke undefined behavior at run time. Warnings for out of bound accesses for vector subscription can be enabled with -Warray-bounds.

This can have surprising results when used on big-endian systems, so Arm’s [Arm C Language Extensions](https://github.com/ARM-software/acle/blob/51ff7c58450255755a07d1a0d99329984e784e79/main/acle.md?plain=1#L4682) recommend to use `vget_lane` if you are using other Neon intrinsics like `vld1` in the same code path.

Comment: It is a little unclear what the relevant base type for `uint16x8_t` is given that it is not declared using `__attribute__((vector_size(something)))`, but rather is a `typedef` from `__simd128_uint16_t`, which happens to be a gcc builtin. Can you clarify the answer in this regard?

Comment: That’s a reading I hadn’t considered! The base type and size are as you would expect from the type name, with the [internal code][1] setting up the built in from other type fragments and the number of elements in the type - but I think you’re right that this is undocumented and the similarity in behavior for GCC Vector Extensions and the built in Neon types is left implicit. [1]: https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/aarch64/aarch64-builtins.cc;h=c21476d7ae963450b12efa24418ce4004a3c74bf;hb=HEAD%5D